# Is there anything wrong with this logic

Tags: php, html

Am a beginner. Am working On a  page. I have the following code. But the echo doesnt give any response. The name on the account number input is accountNumber on the html form.

i.e

```
<form action="go.php" method="post">
        <label>Enter Acc. No</label>
        <input type="number" name="accountNumber" required>
        <button type="submit">GO</button>
</form>
```

And the go.php page

```
<?php

        error_reporting(E_ALL | 
       E_WARNING | E_NOTICE);

       ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);

         if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
      session_start();
   
         }
  
       
     
      if(!isset($_SESSION['login']))
    {
     echo (" 
       <script>location.href='../clogin/'</script>");
        die();
        }

        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
      {
          
  
         
     include_once('db.php');
       //get post details from user
                 
        $accountNumber = $_POST['accountNumber'];
              
          $sql = "select * from customer
           where account_number = '$accountNumber' ";           
     
               $result = mysqli_query($connection,$sql);
               
   

        if(!$result) 
        {
        die('ERROR:' . mysqli_error($connection));
    }
    
          if ($result->num_rows>0)

        {
    

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {  
    
  
  
  
          if ($accountNumber !== $row['account_number')           
          { 
      echo"invalid";
    
         }
 
 
 
 
         else
           {
                        
       echo"valid";                           
           

              
         }//end of while        
           
        }// end of result count



              }// end submit       
              
?>
```

It just keeps reloading the html form page with no errors. Thanks in advance. I have tried several things but i cant really figure what the issue is.

Comment: **Warning:** Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

Comment: https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli also contains good examples of writing safe SQL using mysqli. Parameterising your queries will also greatly reduce the risk of accidental syntax errors as a result of un-escaped input values.

Comment: add `name="submit"` to button form, why use script location when you can use php like `header('location:yourpage.php');`? please learn how to use prepare stmt for prevent sql inject.  on `$row['account_number'` you forgot `]`

Comment: Thanks very much. I will correct myself

Answer (score 0):

Your button should consist of `name` as `post` and `get` methods works based on it.

It should be as

```
<form action="go.php" method="post">
    <label>Enter Acc. No</label>
    <input type="number" name="accountNumber" required>
    <button type="submit" name="submit">GO</button>
```

**Note:** Please use prepared statements to prevent **SQL injections**